# Increase poltergeist timeout for a specific capybara click_button call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I have a rails project, which I'm testing with rspec/capybara/poltergeist/phantomjs. I know I can increase the general poltergeist timeout with the general settings

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 2.minutes)
end
```

But is there a way to increase the timeout for a specific request?

I have a page with a button (id=submit) which kicks off a longish (90-120 seconds) running process, before returning. I'm working on optimizing the back end to shorten the request time, but in the meanwhile, I want to increase the timeout for that specific request when testing, so something along the lines of

```
click_button 'submit', wait: 180
```

Comment: It seems you can do this by [switching drivers out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383385/capybara-increase-max-allowed-page-load-time)

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
Capybara.using_wait_time(180) do
   click_button 'submit'
end
```

Another thing you can do is

```
 # capybara.rb

 Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
     Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 30)
 end

 Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_long do |app|
     Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 180)
 end


 # wherever.rb

 session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist_long)
 session.visit("http://thatlongwaittime.com")
```

Comment: Doesn't this affect Capybara's wait_time, which is the amount of time Capybara will wait for javascript and other non-intrinsic page assets to load, and execute, rather than Poltergeist's read timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Timeuouts for specific requests can be increased by increasing the value of default wait time which is generally configured in you env.rb file.
To understand this well lets take below mention code:

Cucumber file:

```
When Joe is on abc page
Then Joe clicks submit button
```

Step definition for clicking submit button:

```
Then(/^Then Joe clicks submit button$/) do
  Capybara.default_wait_time = 120  // increasing the default wait time to 180 seconds
  click_button('submit')  // performing the action
  Capybara.default_wait_time = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME  // reset the wait time to its default value after clicking submit button.
end
```

**Note:** The value of DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME can be configured in env.rb file

Hope this helps :)